want to add linux to MB pro 7,1 -- any recommendations for which version?
I have a 2010 MB pro, version 7,1, and want to add some version of Linux to it.  Not sure if I want to use Elementary OS (will it even work?) Or ubuntu.  Someone mentioned Debian as well, but I'm not sure.
8 gb RAM, intel dual core processor, 2.4 ghz, NVIDIA GeForce 320M GPU, 256 MB.
Not sure what else I can provide.  I think it's compatible according to the ubuntu Desktop System requirements, but I'm new to this, so my apologies if I'm not providing enough information.
The EOS system requirements state that it requires an intel i3 or dual core compatible processor for the newest version.  I was thinking about sticking with EOS, but not sure if my MB Pro can handle it. Can anyone tell me if the processor on my MB pro will work with it?
Any recommendations about which one?

Your 2010 MacBook Pro with an Intel dual-core processor should be compatible with Elementary OS (EOS), Ubuntu, and Debian. The processor is within the requirement for EOS, which needs an Intel i3 or a dual-core processor, so it should work fine. EOS is designed to be a lightweight and user-friendly distribution, making it a good choice for older hardware.
However, since your MacBook Pro has an NVIDIA GeForce 320M GPU, you might need to check if the latest version of EOS provides good support for that graphics card. Both Ubuntu and Debian have more extensive hardware support and might be safer choices if you're looking for a more stable experience.
Here's a quick breakdown of your options:

Elementary OS: Lightweight and user-friendly, based on Ubuntu. It should work well but might need some additional tweaks for the NVIDIA GPU.
Ubuntu: Well-supported and stable with broad compatibility, especially for older Macs. It may use more system resources than EOS but is still manageable.
Debian: The most lightweight and flexible option. It requires more manual configuration but can run very efficiently on older hardware.

Given your setup, I'd recommend starting with Ubuntu or Elementary OS (EOS) if you're looking for an easier setup. If you want a more hands-on experience and are willing to tinker, Debian could be a good fit.

Thanks.  May I ask if you can guide me to where I might learn if the newest version of EOS can support my graphics card (or is that the other way around)?
